# Не распознается переменная Jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Я пытаюсь добавить свой метод для валидации поля с помощью jQuery.validator.addMethod.Но мне пишет "Unresolved variable validator".Я хочу ,что бы 1e2 распознавало как число "100".

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
    {

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("validcb1", function()
        {
            console.log(Number ( document.getElementById("InputY")));
            if ( Number ( document.getElementById("InputY")) ) return false ;
            else return  true;
        },"Вы ввели не число");
        var form=$('#myform');
        form.validate({


            rules:
            {
            InputX: {
                required: true

            },
            InputY: {
                validcb1:true,
                number:true,
                required: true ,
                max: 3 ,
                min: -5,


            },
            InputR:
                {
                required: true

            }},
                messages:
                    {
                        InputX: {
                            required: "Заполните X",

                            },
                        InputY:
                            {
                        required: "Заполните Y",
                                validcb1: " Вы ввели не число",
                                max: "Число должно быть меньше 3" ,
                                min: "Число должно быть больше -5",

                    },
                        InputR: {
                            required: "Заполните R",

                        },
                },

            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {

                if (element.attr("name") == "InputX") error.insertAfter($("label[name=LabelX]"));
                if (element.attr("name") == "InputY") {
                    console.log(element.value)
                    error.insertAfter($("label[name=LabelY]"));
                }
                if (element.attr("name") == "InputR") error.insertAfter($("input[name=InputR]"));

            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Возможно вы не подключили дополнительный файл jquery.validate.min.js
2. Возможно вы подключили jquery.validate.min.js раньше чем
   jquery-3.2.1.min.js
3. Возможно версия jQuery сильно старая

Comment: jquery.validate.min.js - где взять актуальную версию этого файла?